# CSSの表示ずれを直したい。

Tags: html, css

postsとsidebarの下にfooterを配置して、
footerの上部にボーダーを引くということをしたいのですが、うまくいきません。

これはドットインストールというサイトのWordpressの講義10番の画像で、
こういう形にしたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、私がコードをまねて書くとfooterの上部がpostsとsidebarの上部と同じ位置の
認識なってしまっており、footerの上部がpostsの下部に配置された状態になりません。
（以下のようになってしまいます。）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コードを掲載させて頂きますので、どこが間違っているのかをご指摘いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

■HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>はじめてのWordPress</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header" class="container">
            <h1><a href=""></a>はじめてのWordPress</h1>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div id="main" class="container">
            <div id="posts">
                posts
            </div><!-- /posts -->
            <div id="sidebar">
                sidebar
            </div><!-- /sidebar -->
        </div><!-- /main -->
        <div id="footer" class="container">
            footer
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </body>

</html>
```

■CSS

```
body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Verbana;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.8;
}

.container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hodden;
}

/* header */
#header {

}

    h1{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 15px 0
    }

    .menu {
        background: #f39800;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 12px;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
    }

        .menu > li {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .menu a {
            padding: 10px 0;
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
        }

        .menu a:hover {
            background: #ffc35c;
        }


/* posts */

#posts {
    float: left;
    width: 435px;
    border: 1px solid #111;

}


/* sidebar */

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;

}

/* footer */

#footer{
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #aaa;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: 自己解決した場合、回答として記載した方がよろしいかと思います。私の回答はコーディングミスに気がつかない誤った回答なので削除します。

Answer (score 1):

> .container {
>       width: 600px;
>       margin: 0 auto;
>       overflow: hodden;
>   }

overflow: hidden;に修正すれば大丈夫かと。

Comment: マイナス票が入っていますが、実際このタイポが原因のようですので、これが正しい回答です。